# Servlet for static resources

Tags: static

I have made a servlet for static resources to IBM WAS8 but when i enter to the web, i always see same error:

"Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed."

My servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class test extends HttpServlet
{    
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, and GlassFish 
private static final String COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "default";

// Resin 
private static final String RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "resin-file";

// WebLogic 
private static final String WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "FileServlet";

// WebSphere 
private static final String WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "SimpleFileServlet";


public String scanDefaultServlet(){
    if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null) {
        return COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
    } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null) {
        return RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
    } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null){
        return WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
    } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null){
        return WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot determine what Server you currently use");
    }       
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(req, resp);
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(this.scanDefaultServlet());
    HttpServletRequest wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
            public String getServletPath() {return "";}
    };

    rd.forward(wrapped, resp);
}
```

¿Any idea? ¿Do you suggest my another solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The idea for this servlet seems to have been take from Spring framework's [DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1204d2aef4afdefb4ba73c86565aab3f5b2a6931/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.java). You can take a look at the code to see how it differs from yours. The extra un-necessary thing you seem to be doing is this

```
HttpServletRequest wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
            public String getServletPath() {return "";}
    };
```

Any specific reason for doing this ?

Comment: I have another issue with the DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.